# How to access data within an array of objects sent from client side?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

Below is how I post my data to my NodeJS API using React JS and Fetch. My Problem is that I don't know how to access the sent array of objects from client within my nodejs api route. If you have any other questions about my code please comment below.

```
 fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/testSub', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(teamSheet),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`
        }
      }).then(res => {
        this.props.history.push('/Login');
      });
```

This is how i'm currently attempting to access the array of objects

```
   router.post('/testSub', auth, async function(req, res) {
          //GET ARRAY
       const sheet = {
        teamsheet.playerNumber = req.body.playerNumber,
        teamsheet.playerName = req.body.playerName,
        teamsheet.playerPosition = req.body.playerPosition
    };
      next();
    });
```

Comment: You are sending the data in JSON format. You should parse the JSON on the server to a JS object. Try `JSON.parse(req.body)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure your teamSheet variable is an Object, with an array included. Your fetch function looks valid. On the node side you should be able to access it in the request body.

```
// Client Fetch
var players = [{
   name: 'John',
   number: '11',
   position: 'Pitcher',
 },{
   name: 'Mary',
   number: '22',
   position: 'Catcher',
 }]

var teamSheet = { players: players }

// Fetch...
fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/testSub', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(teamSheet),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`
    }
  }).then(res => {
    this.props.history.push('/Login');
  });


// Server
var players = req.body.players
```